# resetting jquery minicolors color value

Tags: jquery, colors

I have successfully implemented [minicolors](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/) for my site.  I've got one problem though, how can i create a new instance of minicolors from click event using a new hex color as a default or new value?

here's how my code looks like:

```
$('input.minicolors').minicolors({
        change: function(hex, opacity){
            console.log(hex);

        }
    });
```

//my attempt to recreate the instance, doesn't work

```
   $('input.minicolors').minicolors({
       value: '#ededed'
   });
```

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question- but I was trying to do this today and ended up here.

Correct approach for the current version:

First, initialize the input (if new)

```
$('#someID').minicolors();
```

Second, change the color

```
$('#someID').minicolors('value','#00FF00');
```

Note: you can't combine initializing and setting the color in the same step. However, you *can* pre-set the color by storing it in the value of the input.

Comment: $('#someID').minicolors('value':'#00FF00'); doesn't work for me, $('#someID').minicolors('value','#00FF00'); works

Comment: Hi Mike, As Intuitisoft pointed out, replace the colon : with a comma ,

Answer (score 1):

Look at their documentation:

> settings
>
> Gets or sets a control's settings. If new settings are passed in, the control will destroy and re-initialize itself with any new
>   settings overriding the old ones.

I conclude from that, the following will do what you want:

```
$('input.minicolors').minicolors('settings', {
  value: '#ededed'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked with this code:

```js
$("input.minicolors").val("#ffffff");

$('input.minicolors').minicolors('settings', {
    value: '#ffffff'
});
```